In flip flop datasheets, why is the clock input called CP?
Why is the clock input pin in flip flops referred to as CP? Is there a reason to avoid referring to it as CLK?
Link to example datasheet: https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/916/74LVC1G175_Q100-1480587.pdf

Yeah, please show an example. I don't remember I noticed such a difference before.

I have seen CP used. I have also seen CLK and CK. It depended on the manufacturer.

I'm not sure at all, but for decades I've assumed the P was for "pulse". Never even questioned it! Funny how a fresh mind can shed light on assumptions.

The datasheet you provided is for a positive-edge triggered flip flop.  This means that the flop captures the data input on the positive edge of the clock input.  Perhaps the P in CP refers to positive (as opposed to negative).  This is an educated guess since the datasheet does not explicitly state this, nor do I see any elaboration on the Nexperia site.
There is no standard for naming flop signals.  But, I agree, CK, CLK, CLOCK are more common names.

CP is usually an abbreviation of Clock Pulse.

@PeterSmith: That is very likely.  Can you cite a reference?

From the datasheet: Information on the data input is transferred to the Q output on the LOW-to-HIGH transition of the clock pulse.

"Perhaps the P in CP refers to positive" - that would imply the use of "CN" for devices clocked on the negative edge, and I can't recall ever seeing that, anywhere.

@Finbarr: I see CN in standard cell libraries.
